# (sql plus) How to prevent auto rounding in oracle database?

Tags: sqlplus

I have the values 33.75, 48.75 and 26.25

so how can I display them as they are without rounding them to 34, 49 and 26?

```
SQL> SELECT p.price "Price in SAR"
  2  FROM payment p;

      Price in SAR
      ------------
      49
      49
      34
      26
      26
      26
      34
      49
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's due to the datatype of the column:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313

```
create table t1 (col1 number (5));
insert into t1 values (33.75);
insert into t1 values (48.75);
insert into t1 values (26.25);
insert into t1 values (10.50);
create table t2 (col1 number (5,2));
insert into t2 values (33.75);
insert into t2 values (48.75);
insert into t2 values (26.25);
insert into t2 values (10.50);

select * from t1;

      COL1
----------
        34
        49
        26
        11

SQL> select * from t2;

      COL1
----------
     33.75
     48.75
     26.25
      10.5

SQL> select to_char(col1, '99.99') from t2;

    TO_CHA
    ------
     33.75
     48.75
     26.25
     10.50
```